# Why are these two identical inline divs misaligned when one has text and the other doesn't?

Tags: html, css

So here are two identical divs:

HTML

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

CSS

```
#left, #right
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

These render just fine, as two identical boxes side-by-side (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/URy59/).

[image: inline divs]

But with text in one div, and none in the other, they're misaligned! (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/URy59/1/)

This...

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

...results in:

[image: misaligned divs]

This behaviour is reproducible using `<span>` as well.

What causes this, and why? What's a good solution to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The short answer**: set the `vertical-align` property to `top`.

**The longer answer**: An inline element's [default vertical alignment is baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). When your divs have no content, they line up fine. However when you added the text, the browser then will move the div downward so that the text sits on the baseline:

[image]

By changing the alignment to top, you align the divs the way you need.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8Z24Q/)**

Comment: So helpful. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I LOVED YOUR SHORT ANSWER

Answer (score 3):

You need to vertically align your elements:

```css
#left, #right {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/URy59/3/).