# Div move down relative to another

Tags: html, css

Please help me. I would like to have two divs on the same line, but one was move down.

```
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;display:inline-block;">
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;background:#000000;"></div>
</div>

<div style="height:200px;width:200px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #000000;">
1<br>2</div>
```

example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/9TZsy/)

Comment: _"on the same line, but one move down."_ I'm confused.

Comment: @Adsy sorry for my english )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these two identical inline divs misaligned when one has text and the other doesn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990281/why-are-these-two-identical-inline-divs-misaligned-when-one-has-text-and-the-oth)

Comment: @j08691 oh yeah, my topic is duplicate. may be someone will find with my words..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the same [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to both of the outer `div`s.

```
vertical-align: top;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/9TZsy/1/)

BTW - It's highly not advisable to use inline styles. Use out-of-line CSS file/block to make things better.

- [Best practices: Avoid using inline-styles](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm)
- [What's so bad about in-line CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `vertical-align:top;`

add the css `vertical-align:top;` to the `<div>`'s that have `display:inline-block;`

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/9TZsy/2/

here's a great article on this: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/
another: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left` to both instead of `display:inline-block`

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/9TZsy/3/